# Permalinks broken regularly

Tags: permalinks, 404-error

On one of my sites the permalinks are broken regularly. After saving them again it's all fine but a few days later the permalinks result in not found and I have to save them again.

There are no errors in the log files and I also deactivated all plugins which might impact rewrites/permalinks.

Due to the fact that it happens over time it's hard to see if maybe a plugin is causing the issue.

Any idea?

Comment: Have you looked at the help forums for all of your plugins to see if any issues are mentioned there? Can you work out which plugins might affect the rewrites to narrow things down? Installing the WP debugging plugins may help you as they have a rewrite inspector in their toolkit. Is your 404 generated by WP, indicating a rewrite rule issue, or by your web server, indicating a .htaccess issue?

Comment: I happen to have the same problem right now. Did you ever manage to fix this issue? Thanks...

Comment: Honestly, I can't remember anymore which project it was :(

Answer (score 0):

I once had a problem like this. On my site was a malware and it edited a .htaccess file. Check by FTP that your .htaccess file is not changed. If yes, scan your site by any online malware scanner or any security Wordpress plugin.